# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) when checking with if condition

Tags: c, valgrind

```
int t_parse(char* target, FILE* fp) 
{   
char cuts = ':';
char * tok;
char ln[BUFF_SIZE];

if (lnCnt == 0) 
{
    lnCnt = 1;
}

while (!feof(fp)) 
{   
    int i = 0;
    int hop = 1;
    char c;
    while (hop) 
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (feof(fp)) 
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                return 0;
            }
            ln[i] = '\0';
            hop = 0;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') 
        {
            ln[i] = '\0';
            hop = 0;
        }
        else if (i == BUFF_SIZE) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%i: Error of long line\n", lnCnt);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (hop) 
        {
            ln[i] = c;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (ln[0] != '#' && ln[0] != '\t' && ln[0] != '\0') 
    {   
        tok = strtok(ln, &cuts);
        if (tok == NULL) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: Error of invalid target\n", lnCnt);
            exit(1);
        }
        else 
        {
            strcpy(target, tok);

            for (int j = 0; j < BUFF_SIZE; j++) 
            {
                if (target[j] == ' ') 
                {
                    target[j] = '\0';
                    return lnCnt++;
                }
            }
            return lnCnt++;
        }
    }
    lnCnt++;
}       
return 0;
}
```

After running Valgrind Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)
    ==2469==    at 0x10938F: t_parse (text_parsing.c:81)

Which is 
    else 
            {
                strcpy(target, tok);

```
            for (int j = 0; j < BUFF_SIZE; j++) 
            {
                if (target[j] == ' ') 
                {
                    target[j] = '\0';
                    return lnCnt++;
                }
```

line 81 is if (target[j] == ' ') 
I am check here so I am not sure why is there a memory leak?
i ran the command valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes --read-var-info=yes 537make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tok` is string copied into `target`.  It will be terminated with a '\0' character.

Then you are looping through the characters in `target`, and will terminate on a matching space character.  However, you are moving beyond the end of the string in `target` in the case when no space character is found, which is uninitialised and could contain anything--so valgrind warns you of this.

One other issue:  `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`  In this, delim points to a string of delimiters, not a single character.  So `char cuts = ':';` should be `char *cuts = ":";`

Comment: How do you suggest I fix it? I tried to initialize target bu using a for loop.    ...............      for (int j = 0; j < BUFF_SIZE; j++)
                     {
                      (target[j] == 'a');
                     }...................    I tried target = & char var. .........  No luck

Comment: You cannot say:   target[j] == 'a';  == is the equality operator.  You need the assignment operator =

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Tried .... for (int j = 0; j < BUFF_SIZE; j++)
                                {
           target[j] = 'a';
                                }..... Still same error

Comment: I am surprised you would get that same exact valgrind warning after initialising the buffer, unless you are copying in unitialised data from the strcpy() further up; yes, that may be the problem?  Also refer to my edited answer.

Comment: after the strcpy(), it would be interesting to printf() target, to see if it is ok according to valgrind

Answer (score 0):

valgrind is not saying anything about a leak. It is showing off another of its features. It has detected that you are testing the content of memory that you did not initialize. It means that `target` contains undefined data. If you want more detailed answer you have to show how you set up `target`

Comment: i declared int t_parse(char* target, FILE* fp)  and then i strcpy(target, tok);  I have not used target anywhere else

Comment: you need to show where you set it up in the code that calls t_parse, you passed it in as the first parameter

Comment: the probable cause is that you are looping for BUF_SIZE bytes, you should probably be only looping till `strlen(target)`

Comment: I have tried initializing target to a char. I have tried  for (int j = 0; j < BUFF_SIZE; j++)
                     {
                      (target[j] == 'a');
                     }              at the beginning of the function. Still dosent work. I tried changing the for loop at line 80 to strlen(target). No luck